# How to add as a dependency a library (unofficial API for Snapchat) in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is the link to this unofficial Java SnapChat client: https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap

Can anyone suggest the steps to add the above library in Android Studio?

Comment: You should look up on how to add maven projects as dependencies to Android studio project. It looks like it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463908/how-to-import-a-maven-module-to-an-android-studio-project

Comment: But I don't have the gradle compile dependency for this library. So may be I have to add this by creating an executable jar of this library and then add that jar in my project. But I am not able to create and run  an executable jar for this project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the developer has discontinued [the project](https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap/issues/50)

However to test for yourself, run this in the terminal:

1. git clone https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap.git && mvn clean compile package
2. Then copy the generated JavaSnap-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file from the `target` folder and copy it into the folder in your app directory called `lib`. Try rebuilding the project and you should be good to go.