# How To Add Maven Dependency (Android Studio)

Tags: xml, maven, android-studio, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

I have this code below..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.gujun.android.taggroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

But where do you put this in Android Studio? I've already placed a dependency in build.gradle which is **compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'**

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/31927339/3678308??

Answer (score 27):

In Android Studio 3.0 and above, you can just copy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.gujun.android.taggroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

into build.gradle, and it automatic converts it to:

```
implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue just now. I was trying to use [khttp](https://khttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in an Android app. Here's the XML that library gave me:

```
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

...and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jkcclemens</groupId>
    <artifactId>khttp</artifactId>
    <version>-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

What I ended up doing was editing the root `build.gradle` file and adding this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I edited the app's gradle file, and added this line to the existing `dependencies { .... }` section:

```
compile 'com.github.jkcclemens:khttp:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

Once done, I hit the "try again" or "sync" button on the yellow bar that appeared to get *Android Studio 3.0.1* to recognise the changes I'd made.

I followed the instructions on the [JitPack homepage](https://jitpack.io/).

Comment: This was helpful, but did you ever try in a Kotlin Multiplatform project. I tried and it worked for the Android target, but not for common or iOS. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: @ArjunKalidas Unfortunately, I have no idea what you mean by a "Kotlin Multiplatform project", so I can't help you there :-/
I'm still a beginner when it comes to writing Android apps. I've only tested this using Android Studio targeting a virtual Android device in a regular Android app project.
Feel free to contribute your own answer if you manage to figure it out.

Comment: Sure, will do. I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 2020.3.1 (maybe before), they added `dependencyResolutionManagement` in the `settings.gradle`.  So if you put something in `build.gradle` the default was to not search the added repository and fail.

One solution is to add your additional repository to the `settings.gradle` file, and change the `RepositoriesMode` to `PREFER_SETTINGS`.

`settings.gradle:`

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS) // CHANGED THIS LINE
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'} // ADDED REPO
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```