# NanoHTTPD - unable to add gradle dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, nanohttpd

I am trying to add [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) to my Android project.

As mentioned in README.md, I added

```
dependencies {
    runtime(
       [group: 'org.nanohttpd', name: 'nanohttpd', version: '2.3.1'],
    )
}
```

it is giving error:

```
Could not find method runtime() for arguments [{group=org.nanohttpd, name=nanohttpd, version=2.3.1}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I also tried adding

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

mentioned elsewhere, but same error.

I tried the usual way:

```
implementation 'org.nanohttpd.nanohttpd:2.3.1'
```

it gives error:

```
Failed to resolve: org.nanohttpd.nanohttpd:2.3.1:
```

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 
There seem to be so many people happily using it in Android. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your gradle file, separate group and artifact ids with a `:` instead of `.`. That is, replace

```
implementation 'org.nanohttpd.nanohttpd:2.3.1'
```

with

```
implementation 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1'
```

Comment: I was just about to figure the same out from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506976/how-to-add-maven-dependency-android-studio