# How to use liblouis on java ( Android)?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, braille

i am student and i am trying to use liblouis on java , but I don't know how to use and install.
For example , I want to read text from editText and translte it to braille word. How can i do? Thank you a lot!

EDIT: I found this on github , but still don't know how to use :
https://github.com/liblouis/liblouis-java

Comment: You can probably use it as module .. See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463908/how-to-import-a-maven-module-to-an-android-studio-project) maybe it can help .. You can download the source and add it module .. and dependencies from POM to gradle this can be done manually also .. try it

Comment: Thank you for your help!.But i can't add it module anymore. May be my mistakes or it can't

Comment: Create your own module as java library and copy paste the code .. add the dependency fro  Pom to gradle . you can find same gradle dependencies for Maven one ..